# Open an iframe after submit form

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a form and I want that when it validate all the information and all its OK open a Iframe with fancybox saying:

"Thanks for register... "

I test this in the jquery that manage the form:

```
$.fancybox( {href : 'http://www.google.com.uy', title : 'Lorem lipsum'} );
```

PD: That url is to test, but nothing happend

I´m using codeigniter and php.

Comment: Firstly, have you got [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/howto) loaded as described on the linked page..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem might be that you are not specifying the content `type`. Which should be 
`iframe` in your case.

```
$.fancybox({href : 'http://www.google.com.uy', title : 'Lorem lipsum', type: 'iframe'});
```